# Using CSS classes in the Drupal 7 form API

Tags: css, forms, api, drupal-7

I have a checkbox defined in a form:

```
$form['membership_block']['membership_info_is_verified'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('<strong>I confirm my information is correct.</strong>'),
  '#description' => t('Select the checkbox here to confirm your information is correct, then be sure to <strong>click the Save button</strong> below to save your change.'),
);
```

I would like the title and description to be surrounded by a box with a light green background. I have not been able to figure out how to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

Form elements can have (optional) elements '#prefix' and '#suffix'.

```
$form['membership_block']['membership_info_is_verified'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div class="green_background">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  // ...
);
```

This way you can surround the HTML code of Form elements with additional code.